# Ошибка "No module named 'selenium'", python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, spyder

Впервые работаю с selenium

Имеется вот такой код(совсем сырой, но уже не варящий):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,executable_path=r"C:\...\chromedriver.exe", )

browser.get('https://vynosmozga.ru/reg/classic-175')

xpath = '//*[@id="form"]/div[2]/div[1]/input'
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).send_keys('')
```

При запуске в Spyder пишет:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Pasha/Desktop/Bot/reg.py', wdir='C:/Users/Pasha/Desktop/Bot')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\...\reg.py:1
    from selenium import webdriver

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Selenium установлен на нужную версию python и в самом spyder версия написана custom, т е та, которая установлена у меня, но все равно выдает такое вот

Драйвер уже установлен на нужную версию хром

Как это решить? Подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Проверьте, импортируется ли библиотека в IDLE. Если импортируется — криво подключена к Spyder. Нет — криво установлена вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, хорошим вариантом будет проверить корректность установки и переустановить selenium через

```
pip install selenium
```

Скорее всего, установится версия 4, поэтому нужно будет проверить код.
К тому же, вы руками прописываете путь к драйверу Chrome. Лучше это дело поставить на автоматику, воспользовавшись webdriver_manager. Тогда не придётся каждый раз обновлять это вручную

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://vynosmozga.ru')
```

[PyPI к webdriver_manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)

Comment: Попробовал переустановить selenium и установить webdriver manager, и заменить часть кода с ручным путем на ваш фрагмент кода, проверил через pip list, все правильно установилось, но, к сожалению, та же ошибка